# C#, ASP MVC 4, Web API, "No type was found that matches the controller named..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

Here's my problem.  I inherited a project solution that has 3 pieces.  A Sharepoint page project, an API project and an SSIS project.  I have been adding and learning as needed and now I need guidance.  Most recently I added 2 standard MVC 4 webpages into the WEB Api project to CRUD 2 new tables.  After doing that I added a new Web API endpoint to query part of the new data for a new analysis page to be added to the Sharepoint project.  My problem is that no matter how I configure the routes I cannot get the Endpoint to respond. I found out today that there are 2 (or more?) engines that do the routing, Web API and ASP MVC and I believe that the fact that I've mixed the 2 styles in the project is my issue...

Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp;

namespace API_MetricsWarehouse
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // enable CORS
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // jsonp
        var jsonpFormatter = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        config.Formatters.Add(jsonpFormatter);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Sites",
            routeTemplate: "api/sites/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ReportDates",
            routeTemplate: "api/reportdates/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SafetyDates",
            routeTemplate: "api/safetydates/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

`
And my RouteConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace API_MetricsWarehouse
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

And my Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace API_MetricsWarehouse
{
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
}
```

And my latest controller...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using API_MetricsWarehouse.Models;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;


namespace API_MetricsWarehouse.Controllers
{
public class SafetyDatesController : ApiController
{
    private MetricsWarehouseEntities db = new MetricsWarehouseEntities();

    // GET: api/SafetyDates
    public IQueryable<SafetyDates> GetSafetyDates()
    {            
        var result = db.SafetyAnalysis1.AsQueryable();

        result = result
            .GroupBy(x => x.YearMonth)
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.YearMonth);

        return result
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(a =>
                new SafetyDates
                {
                    SafetyYearMonth = ((DateTime)a.YearMonth).ToString("yyyy MMM")
                })
            .AsQueryable();


    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
}
```

The new controller is almost a carbon copy of the ReportDates Controller but the endpoint will not fire.  (ReportDates still works great...)  Anyone can help me untwist this?  I'd rather not fall back to the old project and pull the MVC pages out and put them in another project but I will if that is the only way to go...

Comment: What is the url you are trying ?

Comment: https://internalSite.com/_metrics/api/safetydates:  broken  https://internalSite.com/_metrics/api/reportdates:  works

Answer (score 0):

So a little more background on my problem.  I've been working in Microsoft products since 1996.  I've worked extensively with Foxpro and VB6 and I've been working in VC# for the last few years.  Still catching up on the ins and outs of the 2013 and 2015 IDE and catching up on Web development and MVC 4 and 5.  The project I recently inherited doesn't have the best docs. (surprise).  While adding code for web applications I've created I followed this procedure:  Make change.  Clean project.  Rebuild Project.  Clean Solution.  Rebuild Solution.  Run solution within the IDE for testing.  This worked fine for the 2 mvc web pages I built.  Once I added the new API I changed my procedure because I wasn't sure how to access the end point.  I tried: Make change.  Clean project.  Rebuild Project.  Clean Solution.  Rebuild Solution and got unexpected results.  I then opened Chrome stand-alone and accessed a currently working API endpoint.  That worked fine but when I tried the new endpoint created above I got the above result.  Eventually I tried to run/change the existing working APIs but found out that I couldn't see any changes.  Finally I DEPLOYED AND PUBLISHED my new solution and the changes showed up.  I fell back to the above code exactly, DEPLOYED AND PUBLISHED my new solution, and the NEW endpoint responded.  My current question is when making changes in 2 projects within a solution (sharepoint solution and WEB MVC 4 PAGES/APIs) what is the minimum process to see all changes occur within the IDE?  Do I have to deploy and publish each time?  If deploy is always necessary, why isn't it part of the publish process?